# Can't create datasets and load images in COCO annotator

Tags: docker, machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, data-annotations

I'm trying to annotate images with COCO key points for pose estimation using https://github.com/jsbroks/coco-annotator. As described in the Installation section I cloned the repo. I installed Docker and Docker-compose. Following this I started the container with `$ docker-compose up` and it is running.

I am now on the website https://annotator.justinbrooks.ca/, I created one user and datasets but they do not appear in the repo `datasets/` folder. I tried to create them manually and to load images in them but they do not appear on the website graphic interface.

I tried to scan, reload the webpage, create other datasets but it does not work. The container seems to work properly, it detects when I put an image in the `datasets/` folder but it throws some errors.

Here is the last lines (I can post the whole log):

```
annotator_webclient | [File Watcher] File /datasets/haricot.jpg for created
annotator_webclient | [File Watcher] Adding new file to database: /datasets/image
annotator_message_q | 2019-05-16 13:01:08.841 [error] <0.461.0> closing AMQP connection <0.461.0> (172.18.0.4:42614 -> 172.18.0.2:5672):
annotator_message_q | missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s
```

Am I missing something fundamental or there is a bug?

I'm using Safari on macOS and I also tried Firefox on Ubuntu 18. I'm not behind a proxy, but maybe some ports are not open or something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creator of COCO Annotator here.

I think you are missing a fundamental concept. The demo runs on the VM and has nothing to do with your local instance.

Once you have the docker-compose running you can access your instance local by typing http://localhost:5000/ .

Comment: Thank you! That wasn't clear form the wiki considering that I'm not familiar with web-based technologies and docker containers.

Comment: When I run docker-compose up command, I am getting this error: Pulling messageq (rabbitmq:3)...
3: Pulling from library/rabbitmq
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.18362 in the manifest list entries

Comment: The issue isn't related to the coco-annotator. I recommend you look around online and since it seems others have had similar issues. https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1100